# Nullifying dependent objects in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
:dependent => :nullify
```

Why would I want to nullify dependant objects, since I don't see a purpose by orphaning database records.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Nullifying is only usefull in very specific cases ; let's say for example you have some projects, which **may or may not** be surveyed by **one and only one** an agent (so its foreign key field referencing the agent **can** be null). If the agent abandons all the surveys he handles (let's say he's been fired), you don't want to destroy the project record, but you can't let it reference to an agent record that won't exist anymore, so you nullify its foreign key field.

Comment: Usually you mark such users as inactive in the database, its quite hard to blow away such user data and there won't be an easy way to surface orphaned data in the UI. Since it becomes more complex if more users leave the system.

Comment: you're right, i did not say it was a good thing to do, just that it's only useful in very specific use cases, when you don't want to keep track of who did what, which is a thing i usually avoid doing  myself... For instance in the example i gave you, just imagine we only want to know the _current_ user surveying the project, if there is one.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but another example of when you might want to do this is adding billable items to an invoice. Let's say the invoice is wrong (user error) and needs to be deleted. You still want to bill the items so you wouldn't want them deleted but you also need to know that they have not been assigned to an invoice yet. In this case you want to delete the invoice and un-assign all records on that invoice to add to a future invoice.

Comment: I have a similar situation. There are shipments which needs to be invoiced. So I am storing the invoice_id in shipment table which can be null. And in case of deletion of an invoice it needs to be nullified.

Answer (score 6):

Consider the case where we have a number of stores and items.  Each item can have many stores and each store can have many items so they are linked with a join table (or cross table).  Lets say that each store can also do its own promotion containing a bundle of items, the place we could store this is on the join table optionally belonging to a promotion.  At the end of the promotion it can be destroyed but we want to retain the link between stores and items and so we'd nullify the `promotion_id`.

```
class Store
  has_many :store_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :items, through: :store_items
end

class Item
  has_many :store_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :items, though: :store_items
end

class Promotion
  has_many :store_items, dependent: :nullify
end

class StoreItem
  belongs_to: :item
  belongs_to: :store
  belongs_to: :promotion, optional: true
end
```

Ideally we might allow the `StoreItem` to have many `Promotion`s and then store date time's on the join table so we know when the `StoreItem` was in a promotion or not but that might be overcomplicating things.